# Linq group by returns anonymous

Tags: c#, .net, linq, gridview

```
var supervisorSummary = Persons.GroupBy(p => p.SupervisorName)
                               .Select(group => new { Name = group.Key, 
                                                      Count = group.Count() })
                               .OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

This query returns Name and Count perfectly.  I bound this output to a GridView and implemented Sorting on both columns.  I then realized that Count is treated as String instead of Integer in GridView.

Is there a way to specify data type for BoundField in Gridview here?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvSupervisorSummary" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableViewState="False" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvSupervisorSummary_Sorting"
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="#cccccc" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2"
            EmptyDataText="No person found." GridLines="none" Width="100%">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#ededed" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Count" HeaderText="Direct Reports Count" SortExpression="Count"/>
            </Columns>
```

I convert to DataView and bind to grid in order to make my sort more dynamic.

```
 DataView dv = new DataView(DataManager.ToDataTable(supervisorSummary));
            dv.Sort = SortExpression;
gvSupervisorSummary.DataSource = dv;
            gvSupervisorSummary.DataBind();
```

My sort expression is defined as

```
private string SortExpression { get { if (Session["SCSortExpression"] == null) Session["SCSortExpression"] = "Count ASC"; return Session["SCSortExpression"].ToString(); } set { Session["SCSortExpression"] = value; } }
```

Comment: [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338038%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) always returns the int value. What gave you the idea that `Count` is `text` value ?

Comment: Are you sure you did not just create the Count Column as string instead of integer?

Comment: It is my mistake, it returns the int.  It appears to be something with GridView which treats all data as String.  Any idea?

Comment: Gridview will treat all data as `string` you need to state what is your problem clearly.

Comment: I found the issue and put as a reply; You can "unhold" the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I messed up the question.  Actually, it is not either the problem with Linq or Gridview.

It is the problem inside my DataTable conversion.

I had the below code to create column without specifying the data type.

```
dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
```

I changed it to below and it works fine

```
dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing dynamic going on here. An anonymous type is not a dynamic object. It's a strongly typed object that you haven't given a name. The compiler is just inferring the type and creating it for you, but you won't be able to do anything dynamic with that type.

If you want to name the type that is returned, you could do this, but it won't change what the `GridView` is doing with it.

```
class MyGroup {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

var supervisorSummary = Persons.GroupBy(p => p.SupervisorName)
                           .Select(group => new MyGroup { Name = group.Key, 
                                                  Count = group.Count() })
                           .OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

It doesn't seem like that's really your problem though. What is the `GridView` doing that you aren't expecting?

Comment: Giving it a name isn't changing anything here.

Comment: added more code to give exact problem;

Answer (score 0):

Count() always returns int value. So, the type of Return object inside the Linq query will also be of type int.

Please check the GridView binding and column data type.

But, there is still a way to specify type inside query, by type casting. 
For your information:

```
var supervisorSummary = Persons.GroupBy(p => p.SupervisorName)
                                   .Select(group => new
                                   {
                                       Name = group.Key,
                                       Count =(Int64)group.Count(),                                   
                                   })
                                   .OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

With this, the type of Count will be long.(instead of int).
However, you can't apply this type casting from string to int.

Please provide your grid view binding code.

Comment: added more code to give exact problem;